# Why can't I run ack from the terminal after I switched from ubuntu to archlinux?

Tags: linux, archlinux, ack

I just switch from ubuntu to archlinux and I installed ack-grep via pacman. However what I found is I can't run `$ ack` from terminal directy. I have to type `$ perl ack` , which is a pain...I wonder if anyone hve experienced similar situation and how do you solve it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the shell you're using. Probably the simplest thing you can do (assuming `bash`) is to create an alias for your desired command, something like:

```
alias acx='perl ack'
```

You'll probably want to place that somewhere in one of your startup scripts, such as `.profile`, or `.bash_profile` in your home directory.

If you're using a different sheel that doesn't support aliases, you can still resort to providing a script to do the translation for you, such as putting the following `acx` file in your path:

```
perl ack "$@" # or however your particular sheel transfers all arguments.
```

Comment: Is the thing you learned how to press on that big green hollow tick mark or the upvote arrow? :-) Just kidding, take your time, you may get a better answer.

Comment: LoL the system will let you have it in 4 mins

Answer (score 4):

There is no reason to use an alias here. It is perl's job to update $PATH in this case. Seeing that the perl package is included in the base group then at most re-logging in should correct everything.

I've also tested this on my system and `pacman -Syu ack` (-Syu should **always** be used when installing).

`# pacman -Syu ack`

`# ack --help` (no error)

**Also**

`$ which ack`

`/usr/bin/vendor_perl/ack`

Comment: Yep, logging out and back in is the correct solution for archlinux.  https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/25670

Answer (score 0):

You should *not* have to make an alias to run ack as the answer above suggests.  Rather than make the workaround alias, let's get your problem fixed.

Why can't you run ack?  What happens when you run it?  Did you get an error message?  What was the error message?